# help with pay pal ipm sending/recieving variables on donation button

Tags: php, xhtml, paypal, paypal-ipn

for PayPal ipn are the variables set or do I set them?
On a donation button how do I find out the amount that was donated?
How do i make a fake donation in sandBox?

Thank you in advance.
If it is to complex for simple code snippets can we im sometime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal provides [code samples](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples) for this.

There are tons of tutorials for this as well. A very detailed tutorial (with video) - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/

Donated amount is obtained from the IPN request itself.

You cannot test IPN in the sandbox directly. Paypal provides a form to make in IPN call from the developer tools. Just login to the developer's section to check it out.

Comment: so all the variables in PayPals ipn reference are automatically set meaning I only have to add custom variables if I want them?